# Is there any place where I can find statistics as to how many browsers accept gzip?

Tags: html, http, browser, http-headers, browser-support

I assume all the modern browsers now send out:

> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch

But is that a good assumption and is there any place where I can find out more about what is accepted?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is a good assumption, and has been for quite a few years. See [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/22223):

> Basically every browser nowadays supports deflate/gzip. [This page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/22223)
>   lists many browsers and version numbers. Here's a summary plus some
>   newer browsers:
>
> - Netscape 6+ (Netscape 4-5 does, but with some bugs).
> - Internet Explorer 5.5+ (July 2000) and IE 4 if set to HTTP/1.1.
> - Opera 5+ (June 2000)
> - Lynx 2.6+ (some time before 1999)
> - Firefox 0.9.5+ (October 2001)
> - Chrome since forever
> - Safari since forever (as far as I can tell)
>
> As you can see: for almost 15 years, there's full support, and nobody
>   uses a more than 15 year old browser.